# Form in HTML Email Not Posting Data

Tags: php, html, forms, email, html-email

I have this question about why my form is not posting data to my PHP script. To unsubscribe from an emailing list I've set up, I send the user that has unsubscribed an email with a form that posts some data.

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <p>This is a confirmation message to confirm that you unsubscribed from the sci-eng email list.</p>
    <p>Click on the button below to confirm your unsubscription.</p>
    <form id="unsubform">
        <div class="form-in">
            <input type="hidden" id="emailkey" name="emailkey" value="key">
            <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="email@domain.com">
            <button class="btn" id="submit" type="submit" formaction="http://redlinks.ca/sci-eng/db/unsubscribe.php" formmethod="post">Unsubscribe</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When on the page that the form is `POST`ed to, I get the "no data" error that I have set up if there is no data in the `$_POST["email"]` variable. I have tried using `var_dump($_POST)`, but that just returns with `array(0) { }` and that isn't working for me.

The thing that confuses me the most is when I copy the exact html from the email, and paste it into a blank page, when I click on submit/unsubscribe it posts the data just fine, and elsewhere on my site I have the exact same script, the only different being the formaction is without the /db in it. The page that one is sent to behaves how it should, showing the propper array of data instead of nothing. That's the only difference.

If it makes any difference, I use Thunderbird for Windows 10 as my email client.

Anyone who thinks they can help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to security issues forms are not supported and not recommended within emails. Most of email clients will warn the user of a risk or simply will disable it and it will not work, like in your case.

The best practice for enabling unsubscribing is by using a link. You can pass any requierd parameter for unsubscribing on the link, for example http://www.example.com/unsubscribe.php?usermail=mail@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

<s>The default method is GET, not POST; you need to specify</s>

```
<form method="post" ...>
```

Maybe a link to this form hosted online might be a better idea; some mail clients do not support showing mails; and maybe more clients might refuse to submit or post them due to security concerns (e.g. webmail interfaces).

Comment: On the button I already have an attribute that is formaction="post", so this probably isn't the problem.

Comment: formaction specifies the action (= URL) of the form, not the method.

Comment: Then I'd assume thunderbird blocked it; or opens it in a browser as a normal link, which will become a GET. Starting a browser with a POST request is not a common function.

Comment: Remember, another script with the exact same content except the link works.

Comment: You mean "and elsewhere on my site I have the exact same script except ..."? I think being on your site in a webbrowser instead of a mail inside a mail software makes the difference, not the /db inside the link.

Comment: Nope. Elsewhere on my site, I have the same unsubscribe setup. When you click the submit button from the form in the email, it works.

Answer (score 0):

TRY WITH:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <p>This is a confirmation message to confirm that you unsubscribed from the sci-eng email list.</p>
    <p>Click on the button below to confirm your unsubscription.</p>
    <form id="unsubform" action="http://redlinks.ca/sci-eng/db/unsubscribe.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-in">
            <input type="hidden" id="emailkey" name="emailkey" value="key">
            <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="email@domain.com">
            <button class="btn" id="submit" type="submit">Unsubscribe</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you won't use POST method so how your form values could be posted to phpScript. Try the following code.

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<p>This is a confirmation message to confirm that you unsubscribed 
   from the sci-eng email list.</p>
<p>Click on the button below to confirm your unsubscription.</p>
<form id="unsubform" method="POST" action="http://redlinks.ca/sci-eng/db/unsubscribe.php">
    <div class="form-in">
    <input type="hidden" id="emailkey" name="emailkey" value="key">
    <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="email@domain.com">         
    <button class="btn" id="submit" type="submit" >Unsubscribe</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not send form for confirmation.Try these steps :

1. Generate unique encrypted key for those email who unsubscribe and store in database
2. Send confirmation link to particular user email with key as (http://domainurl/confirm.php?key=1533c67e5e70ae7439a9aa993d6a3393)
3. Now check key for corresponding email and unsubscribe and also remove key from database